# JavaScript code do not print out messages

Tags: javascript, html

So all of sudden my code no longer prints out anything when executed, the HTML seems to be working but when clicking calculate button nothing happens, (the program is far from done but need to fix the issue with the calculate button first). Have tried to fins syntax errors and small mistakes but I´m guessing there are some left, since it worked at first before adding the if statements.

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="group" content="95">
    <meta name="author" content="Carolina Svantesson">
    <meta name="author" content="Viktoria Hamnér"> 
    <title>Calendar</title>     

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Weekday Calculator</h1> 

    <form id="inputForm">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Year:</td>
            <td><input type ="text" id="year" value="" size="4"></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Month:</td>
            <td><input type ="text" id="month" value="" size="2"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Day:</td>
            <td><input type ="text" id="day" value="" size="2"></td>
        </tr>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type ="button" id="button" value="Calculate" 
                onclick="handleInput(this.form);"></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <p id="output"></p>

    <script language="Javascript">
    function handleInput(form){
       // var form = document.getElementById("inputForm");
        try {
            var strYear = form.year.value;
            var strMonth = form.month.value;
            var strDay = form.day.value;

            var intYear = parseInt(strYear);
            var intMonth = parseInt(strMonth);
            var intDay = parseInt(strDay);

            if (isNaN(intYear))
                throw "Incorrect input, year is not a number. ";
            if (intYear <0 || intYear>9999)
                throw "Incorrect input, year is out of the expected range                          (0--9999)."; 

            if (isNaN(intMonth))
                throw "Incorrect input, Month is not a number. ";
            if (intMonth <1 || intMonth >12)
                throw "Incorrect input, Month is out of expected range(1--12).";

            if (isNaN(intDay))
                throw "Incorrect input, Day is not a number.";
            if (intMonth == 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)
                if (intDay <1|| intDay>31)
                    throw "Incorrect input, Day is out of expected range (1--31).";

            if (intMonth == 4, 6, 9, 11)
                if (intDay <1 || intDay>30)
                    throw "Incorrect input, Day is out of expected range(1--30)";

            if (intMonth == 2)
                if (intYear % 4== 0 && %100 !==0)
                    if (intDay <1|| intDay>29)
                        throw "Incorrect input, Day is out of expected range(1--29)";
            if (intMonth == 2)
                if (intYear %4 !==0)
                    if (intDay <1|| intDay >28)
                        throw "Incorrect input, Day is out of expected range (                                  1--28)";

            var output =" "+ intYear + " " + intMonth + " " + intDay +"är en...";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;

        }
        catch (error){
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="ERROR: " +error;
        }



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

You have

```
if (intYear % 4== 0 && %100 !==0)
```

should be something like this:

```
if (intYear % 4== 0 && intYear % 100 !==0)
```

also you need a closing `}` in your code

Here it is working: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/WGAdoB